# Storing difference in value between two pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Picture of the question on the exam:

[image]

So the question wants us to store the difference between the next node and the previous node's memory location.

```
struct sub_node{
   float data;
   int sub_value; //memory address of next node - previous node
};
```

This is the structure I made for each node. This works fine for all node except for the final and starting node. I can compute the next nodes address by simply doing

```
struct node * next = node_current->sub_value + node_prev; //node_prev is 
        //memory address of the previous node(pointer)
```

And similarly when trying to traverse backwards.

`&NEXT_NODE - 0` gives me an error when storing that as an integer value. (see picture for description) and similarly, `0 - &SECOND_LAST_NODE` also gives me that error. I was wondering what would be the best approach to solving this. (Integer to pointer without cast)

Comment: "gives me an error" - _which_ error, exactly?

Comment: @ForceBru "warning: assignment to 'int' from 'struct sub_node *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]" and "invalid operands to binary - (have 'int' and 'struct sub_node *')
     d->sub_value = 0 - c;" when trying to make d's subtraction value 0-c

Comment: Note that this kind of link-list works best when the elements are being allocated from an array, as often used to happen in Fortran. Then, the deltas can be in record counts not raw pointer values, and the delta size can be restricted to the size of the underlying array.

Comment: This data structure is not possible in standard C, as it's undefined to perform arithmetic on pointers to different objects.  This can only work if all nodes are allocated from a single array (which is atypical for linked lists).

Comment: @GemTaylor I see. The question just wants to us implement methods given that the LinkedList is already filled with nodes and the exam is taken on paper (this is last year's exam I'm trying to practice). I was just trying to implement it on a machine and what sort of primitive type the deltas should be stored in. If it is a delta ie. An address - another address it works fine. Issues just arise when it is a raw pointer value (ie the first and last element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with this code.

Firstly, `sub_value` is an `int`, which is likely of insufficient range to store a difference between pointers.  See [the answer by Saucy Goat](/a/59379017/4850040) for advice to fix that.

Secondly, pointer arithmetic is defined only for pointers that point within the same object in C.  So we'll need our subtraction to work with integer types instead.  For this, there's the `uintptr_t` type:

```
struct sub_node{
   float data;
   uintptr_t sub_value; // relative position of next node
};
```

```
    uintptr_t next_as_int = node_current->sub_value + (uintptr_t)node_prev;
    struct node *next = (struct node*)next_as_int;
```

Your subtraction with 0 is then well-defined, as 0 is a perfectly reasonable `uintptr_t` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ptrdiff_t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Important-Data-Types.html) type, whose use case is exactly this one. It is defined in `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: Or `size_t` or `uintptr_t` on later standards - the type of integer required to represent a difference between array elements or a pointer.

Comment: Great point! I was hesitant to include numeric types since they can change by implementation but I guess it's good someone pointed them out as a possibility :)

Comment: They are in the C standard so should be reliable.

Comment: `int*` is *not* guaranteed to have the same size as other kinds of pointer.  `void*` _is_ guaranteed to be able to represent any kind of pointer (but that's not the only problem).

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks, I'll edit my answer. Also, what do you mean by "not the only problem"?

Comment: @saucy - see my comment to the question - pointer arithmetic is undefined if the pointers don't point within the same object, so we end up needing all the nodes to be in a single array.

Comment: Though I guess converting to `uintptr_t` before the arithmetic might make the operations well-defined (with the corresponding conversion back to pointer in the right place, too).

Comment: @TobySpeight I edited my answer. Thank you for your input! :)